# Pull data into my dashboard using Countifs, Sumif from the same cell in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with pulling information from the same cell across like 50 sheets to a dashboard sheet.
Basically it is for a Project management tool. Each project has a sheet and in the sheet, they record the following from B2-B7: Project Category, Product category, Project Manager, Status, Phase,Project Value

[image]

This data is entered for all projects which are captured on the same cell but different sheets (50 sheets) minus the dashboard sheet.

On the dashboard sheet, I would like to count how many "Upgrade" type projects (cell b2) are "active" or "on hold" (cell b5). Kindly note that all the cells in B columns have drop-downs. I was able to solve this using UDP code shown below, but because this will be an active document (placed on sharepoint), I will prefer to have code that i can run on the dashboard so that it is not affected when it is online. Any help here pls? See code used below

```
Function myCountIf(rng As Range, criteria) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "Dashboard" And ws.name <> "Dashboard 1" Then
            myCountIf = myCountIf + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(rng.Address), criteria)
        End If
    Next ws
End Function
```

Comment: Pretty sure UDFs only run in Excel desktop, not in Sharepoint

Comment: @urdearboy Yes, exactly. Which is why i need a formula to be placed in the cell on the dashboard sheet that will help me calculate total number of "Active" projects or sum of "active projects using either countifs or sumifs function.

Comment: You need a formula if you want this to run on SP, not code